# How to show a login screen before loading the actual shell in Prism framework

Tags: wpf, mvvm, prism

In my application I want to show a login screen first, if the login is successful only then I want to show what is known as a Shell.

How would you structure a simple application that first authenticates the user via some login screen and then opens up the main window that acts as container for further module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=29570

Found the answer in the above thread.
We need to do it in CreateShell method of bootstrapper.

Answer (score 2):

As the example you provided, there are many other threads that deal with this in the Prism codeplex forum, like this one: http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=58292.

I hope this helps.

Thanks,
Damian